# watermark in image using nodejs

Tags: node.js, image, watermark, gm

I have added watermark on image using node_module 'gm', i had make font color grey but i found an bug in that if image content grey color so my watermark merged with image so i can't read the watermark text, that's why i want to create an overlay between image and watermark text but i don't know how i achieve it my current code is

```
const image = gm(__dirname+'/download.jpeg').fill('#ffffff').font('Arial', 10, '#ffffff').drawText(10, 20, "some text");
image.write('result.png', err => {
    if(err) return console.error(err);
});
```

and i don't know how to make overlay between them my actual image is [image]

and my watermarked image is [image]

any help should be appreciate thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there is no such module that can give you the expected result.
But I faced the same problem & came across this module "[node-caption](https://www.npmjs.com/package/caption)" but again this module is also not giving us the expected result. So I have tweaked this module a little bit & made it work as expected.
Here is the URL to the modified module of my git hub repo https://github.com/mohsincynexis/node-caption.
The changes are only in the generate.js file.
Here is the attached image after watermark.[image]